# Should I use a collection of Users or user in a certain class inMVC4

Tags: c#, entity-framework, class, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a Department filled with Users in it
eg Mark is in HR Department and James is also in HR Department etc

I'm just wondering do I use

public virtual ICollection Users { get; set; }

or

public virtual User User { get; set; }

for my department and depot classes which look exactly the same?

```
 public class Department
    {
        public int DepartmentID { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 3)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Administrator")]
        public int UserID { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
    }
```

Can someone also check if I did these few lines correctly in my User class(You can reference it below)

```
    public virtual ICollection<Ticket> Tickets { get; set; } <-Users can have a collection of tickets because they can open as many tickets as they want.   
    public virtual Administrator Administrator { get; set; } <- Only one user can be one type of admin at a time
    public virtual Department Department { get; set; } <- Only one user can be at one department in at a time
    public virtual Depot Depot { get; set; } <- Only one user can be at one depot a time
```

This is my Entity Diagram
[image]

User class

```
    public class User
    {
        public int UserID { get; set; }
        [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 1)]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 1, ErrorMessage = "First name cannot be longer than 50 characters.")]
        [Column("FirstName")]
        public string FirstMidName { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime EnrollmentDate { get; set; }

        public int DepotID { get; set; }
        public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
        public int TicketID { get; set; }


        public string FullName
        {
            get { return LastName + ", " + FirstMidName; }
        }


        public virtual ICollection<Ticket> Tickets { get; set; }    
        public virtual Administrator Administrator { get; set; }
        public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
        public virtual Depot Depot { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: If a `Department` contains multiple `User`, then its `ICollection<User> Users` (but its not clear what the purpose of your `Administrator` table is)

Comment: As quick as always! Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah you should use Department because it'll contain a collection of users.